# When sea water evaporates does it carry small amounts of salt into the atmosphere?

Tags: salinity, evaporation

I’m interested to know, because we live near the beach and all the metal on the outside of our house is corroded.

My dad says it was from the wind picking up spray from the surf, but I’m not so sure.

Comment: salt is only one of the things that makes metal rust other polutants is just as important,if rainwater combines with smog you will have acidic rain.

Comment: Your dad is right. When water evaporates from the sea only the water part of it turns to gas phase (salt stays in the sea). Wind lifts small water droplets containing salt and evaporation of these droplets leaves salt aerosols in air.

Answer (score 3):

Listen to your father ! Yes droplets of spray are carried on the wind several miles . There are any number of corrosion tables listing atmospheric corrosion more severe on sea coasts.  Much of the testing was / is being done at Kure Beach ( N or S ) Carolina.